# React Native Android: how to recompile with -Xlint:deprecation?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I'm upgrading libraries in my React Native project and got this error when I ran `npx react-native run-android`:

```
@react-native-community/cameraroll/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/cameraroll/CameraRollModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

**What I Want To Know:** How do I recompile? What command should I be using with -Xlint:deprecation? Is this something within Android Studio?